# Storing over 100 images in an array

Tags: javascript

I want to store over 100 images in an array, but instead of copying and pasting the path one by one, e.g.:
`var pix = ["picfolder/pic1.jpg", "picfolder/pic2.jpg, "picfolder/pic3.jpg", //and so on...]` is there an easier way to do this?

Particularly, is it possible to store the folders path to simultaneously store all pics in an array and access them with `pix[0]` or `pix[1]` for example?

Comment: Where else would the paths to 100 images come, when not defining them in an array or reading them from a directory / database? You are talking about "storing pictures in an array", but you show an example of storing paths to pictures in array, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I think he wants to know how to read the contents of a directory into a Javascript arra, for which I think he will need either a server-side solution or to use nodejs. But bare Javascript? Unfortunately not, to the best of my knowledge. Here's a pretty neat solution using php: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?300009-List-all-the-files-from-a-folder-into-an-array

Comment: you should provide some more context : Do the names have a simple logic like your example ? or are they really diffrerent (like zzzz.jpg, cdcd.jpg, aaabbb.jpg) ? You want to be able to read the file name and generate the array values, so you can copy it into your code, whatever the names are currently ? Where are you using this JS? in a browser / webpage ? in a node.js server ?

Comment: PS : you are not storing *images* in your array, you are apparently storing *file names* or (*file paths*)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this ?

```
let pix = [];
for(let idx=1; idx <= 250; idx+=1) {
  pix.push(`picfolder/pic${idx}.jpg`);
}
```

The code above will give you an array like this:

```
pix = [ "picfolder/pic1.jpg", "picfolder/pic2.jpg" ... "picfolder/pic250.jpg" ]
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to implement this. For my folder particularly, it contains 250 image files thus I set `idx <= 250`, couldn't get it to work.  Think you could provide a snippet if at all possible?

Comment: @ScottMiller You need to tell more what you are doing. The code above works as described: You get an array with [ "picfolder/pic1.jpg"  ... "picfolder/pic250.jpg" ]`. What else are you doing with the code?

Comment: @ScottMiller Miller "couldn't get it to work"  is something you can hardly make less informative. Please clarify what "doesn't work" : the filenames are wrong ? (in this case, which filenames are you expecting ?) is their an error message ? something else ?